# Unity scripts don't work: "Script class cannot be found"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello everybody,

A few days ago, a new error showed up on my computer: Unity scripts don't work at all. Every time I try to open (new or old) Unity projects, 2 blank errors appear (first screenshot), and when I try to attach a script to a GameObject, and alert dialog box shows (second screenshot). You can also see in the script import settings: "No MonoBehaviour scripts in the file or their names do not match the file name"...

I already tried to uninstall all Unity's related files, reinstall it, uninstall and reinstall Virtual Studio 2019 and SDKs, so if you have an idea of where it could come from, just tell me!

Thanks a lot,

Simon

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Did you rename the script?

Comment: I didn't, the file name is the same as the class name.

Comment: Is the script C# or Unityscript? You've tagged both so it's unclear.

Comment: Sorry for this mistake, it's a C# script !

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is called "Blank Error". Looking for Blank Error Unity you'll find many possible solutions.

For instance:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/four-blank-errors-in-each-new-project.599980/

What fixed it for me was to "install windows update from this link to your 32 bit or 64 bit system accordingly":
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2533623/microsoft-security-advisory-insecure-library-loading-could-allow-remot

Comment: I updated my .NET Core and SDK, restarted my pc, but it didn't change anything, however thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I installed MSVC v140 and v141, Unity 2018.4.13f1 and it seems to work now, after this I tried with Unity 2019.2.15f1, and I think there is an error with this version, I had the same problem.

But right now I can use Unity, that's what I wanted, thanks for all people who helped me !